# Mdframed buggy with LuaTex + Babel + Urdu

Tags: luatex, mdframed, bidi

I recently switched from XeTex to LuaTeX (Texlive 2022) for Urdu, and generally things are going well. However, mdframed seems to have a bug (in XeTeX I never experienced this):

```
    \documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[a6paper,left=1cm, right=1cm, bottom=1.2cm, top=1.5cm]{geometry} 
    \usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
    \mdfdefinestyle{rightbar}{leftmargin=0cm,rightmargin=0cm, topline=false,bottomline=false,rightline=false, leftline=true,align=right}
    \mdfsetup{linecolor=black, linewidth=2pt,backgroundcolor=green}

    \usepackage[english,bidi=basic]{babel}
    \babelprovide[import,main]{urdu}
    \babelfont[urdu]{}{AwamiNastaliq}
    \babelfont[english]{rm}{Source Serif Pro}

    \usepackage{fontspec}

    \setmainfont[Renderer=Graphite,RawFeature={Short forms=All}]{AwamiNastaliq}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{mdframed}[style=rightbar]
    جاتے ہیں اِس راستے پر۔ کیا کریں؟
    \end{mdframed}

    \end{document}
```

In this example, if leftline=true, it shows up on the right and the whole frame appears to the right of it.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use tcolorbox instead. It is more powerfull and more importantly it is actively maintained. So if there are problems with bidi the chance is better to get a correction. With `layout=graphics` it seems to work for your example (I didn't try to fine tune the layout and to correct the length of the border):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[a6paper,left=1cm, right=1cm, bottom=1.2cm, top=1.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
    
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
    \mdfdefinestyle{rightbar}{leftmargin=0cm,rightmargin=0cm, topline=false,bottomline=false,rightline=false, leftline=true,align=right}
    \mdfsetup{linecolor=black, linewidth=2pt,backgroundcolor=green}

    \usepackage[english,bidi=basic,layout=graphics]{babel}
    \babelprovide[import,main]{urdu}

    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Noto Nastaliq Urdu}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{mdframed}[style=rightbar]
    جاتے ہیں اِس راستے پر۔ کیا کریں؟
    \end{mdframed}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green,enhanced,frame hidden,borderline west={4pt}{0pt}{black},sharp corners]
    جاتے ہیں اِس راستے پر۔ کیا کریں؟
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
     
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I realized I had added two Renderers and have deleted \defaultfontfeatures in my example accordingly. However, there seems to be a problem with HarfBuzz as the renderer. The letters are right-to-left but not joined. Graphite with Awami is however rendering correctly, so it works for me. Maybe it was not clear---I wanted a bar to the right. However it does work correctly when I substitute borderline west in place of borderline east. So tcolorbox is working properly with Graphite + Awami. Great!

Comment: I don't have your font and the renderer errored for me  so I changed that for the test.